# Struts combobox is not populating the selected value on validation

Tags: jsp, validation, session, struts2

I have done validation for combobox. If I wont select any value and submit the form field error is coming but if I select some value and submit the form the selected value is not populating.

Note: Its populating the selected value before submitting the form

```
<s:combobox label="" id="NotifSound" cssStyle="padding:0px;width:200px" 
 headerKey="-1" headerValue="--- Select ---" value=" - Add or Select - " 
 list="%{#session.NotificationSoundList}" maxlength="50" name="messageBean.sound"
 labelSeparator="" cssClass="form_textbox" labelposition="left" />
```

Comment: Do you have in your `Action` an object called `messageBean` (with its `Setter`) and inside it a String property called `sound` (with its `Setter`) ?

Comment: Yes I have and I am able to get when I chose a type of sound before clicking submit button. I am facing the problem after clicking the submit button

Comment: While POPULATING the list, you are reading it from `%{#session.NotificationSoundList}`; after submit, you are sending the selected element of the list (or a custom inputed element) to `getMessageBean().setSound()`. There is absolutely NO correlation between what you have "before the submit" (the populated combobox) and "after the submit" (when you send a single selected value). Please check again, or post your Action code...

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem you are experiencing is to use the [session](http://struts.apache.org/development/2.x/docs/accessing-application-session-request-objects.html) variable. Because this variable you should update manually before you return result.

If you submit from the [select tag](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.0.x/docs/select.html) it have the value attribute which is populated when you select something. Then this value is sent to the struts that is set to your action attribute.

Now, the action is executed and you could get the list from the session map and add the value that you get after submit. Then if you return result back to your JSP then new select element will be rendered and repopulated with the values from [session scoped variable](http://struts.apache.org/development/2.x/docs/scope-interceptor.html) that has been already updated by the action.